# CAKEPHP 3: Like condion special character paginate

Tags: cakephp, sql-like, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'm having trouble finding likes with special characters as follows
in the database i have a record with the name `Toan"123`
now, in cakephp 3 i use query ORM

```php
$sqlSub = $sysLogTable
    ->find('all', [
        'fields' => array('id' ,'name')
        'conditions' => array("name LIKE" => "%Toan"%")
    ])
    ->toArray();
```

but I don't get `Toan"123`. How to get `Toan"123` with sql above.
Please help me, I'm stuck

Comment: That's invalid PHP, you cannot put an unescaped double quote in a double quoted string, which you can see from the syntax highlighting, and from the inevitable parser error that you'd receive when running that code. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php**

Comment: thnaks pro, is there any way that can help me to search with the character " ?